# Optimal order for items in game with random early termination

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have n items.  Each item has a value v_i and a continuation probability p_i.  I am going play a game where I pick an item, get its value, and get to keep playing with its corresponding probability.  If I get to continue, I can pick up any remaining item, add its value to my sum, and am again subject to its continuation probability.  If I am lucky, I can play until there are no items left.  I want to pick an ordering to maximize my expected value.

Is there an efficient algorithm to solve this?

Comment: Interesting problem! Out of curiosity, where did this come up?

Comment: You want to rank a list of items for some social media-like platform.  You develop both a probability of like model (person clicks like), and a probability of continuation model (person sees item and keeps scrolling), which give you the v_i and p_i.  You want to rank using them to maximize likes under that model.  It seems like sorting by v_i / (1 - p_i) works.

Comment: Just posted what (I think) is a correct answer. I periodically teach an algorithms course and this would make for a fantastic problem set question. Would you be comfortable with me using this, with attribution?

Comment: Sure, use it without attribution even, which I am sure will make googling the answer harder ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observation you have is correct! You should sort by v_i / (1 - p_i) and list the items in that order.

To see why this works, let's begin by looking at the two-item case. Suppose that you have two items (v1, p1) and (v2, p2). Our goal will be to define some kind of ordering relation ≥ such that (v1, p1) ≥ (v2, p2) if the expected reward for picking (v1, p1) first is better than the expected reward for picking (v2, p2) first.

If you pick (v1, p1) first, your expected reward is v1 + p1 v2, and if you pick (v2, p2) first, your expected reward is v2 + p2 v1. We want to determine what has to happen for

> v1 + p1 v2 ≥ v2 + p2 v1

to occur. With some algebra, we get that this happens if and only if

> v1 - p2 v1 ≥ v2 - p1 v2
>
> v1 (1 - p2) ≥ v2 (1 - p1)
>
> v1 / (1 - p1) ≥ v2 / (1 - p2)

This is what you discovered earlier.

Now, imagine that you choose the elements in any order your like. Let's number them v1, v2, ... , vn based on the order they appear. Now imagine that you've picked these items so that they are not in descending order based on the ordering given above. That means that there must somewhere be two adjacent terms that are out of order. Let's have v_i be the first time this occurs. Then the expected reward will be

> v1 + p1(v2 + p2(v3 + p3(...(v_i + p_i(v_{i+1} + p_{i+1}X))...)

where X is the value from the remaining terms. Imagine that you swap items v_{i+1} and v_i and leave everything else alone. Then your reward will be

> v1 + p1(v2 + p2(v3 + p3(...(v_{i+1} + p_{i+1}(v_i + p_i X))...)

Since the leading terms here are equal and all nonnegative, we can ignkre them for now and focus on the core terms

> v_i + p_i(v_{i+1} + p_{i+1} X)

and

> v_{i+1} + p_{i+1}(v_i + p_i X)

We know that v_i and v_{i+1} are out of order, so

> v_i + p_i v_{i+1} ≤ v_{i+1} + p_{i+1} v_i

Therefore, assuming we perform the swap, we see that

> v_i + p_i(v_{i+1} + p_{i+1} X)
>
> = v_i + p_i v_{i+1} + p_i p_{i+1} X
>
> ≤ v_{i+1} + p_{i+1} v_i + p_i p_{i+1} X
>
> = v_{i+1} + p_{i+1}(v_i + p_i X)

This means that the expected value can only go up as we make the sequence more sorted, so the greedy solution of sorting in descending order by v_i / (1 - p_i) is indeed the optimal solution!

So, yes. Sort by v_i / (1 - p_i) and list things in that order.

Comment: Nice proof! I checked empirically on lots of random examples to confirm.